# How to fix ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken with remotipart gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, remotipart

I'm getting an error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` when I'm trying to submit an Ajax form with a file attached. I want to fix it with remotipart gem, but the error stays after I add remotipart and add `//= require jquery.remotipart` right after `//= require jquery_ujs` in `application.js` as recommended in the docs. Any ideas how to go about this?
I use Rails 5.1.1 and tried different versions of Remotipart with the same result.

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

log:

```
Started POST "/questions/67/answers" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-08-09 16:43:07 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AnswersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "answer"=>{"body"=>"loo"}, "commit"=>"Post your answer", "question_id"=>"67"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:227:in `handle_unverified_request'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:253:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:222:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:in `call'
remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing the order of lines in the `application.js` like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require_tree .
```

But I have no idea why this worked.